# Angularjs 2 beta, updating same data in different browser session

Tags: angular, typescript

i am using Angular js beta version and created one login application.when i open this app in multiple browsers or multiple browser tabs and try to write some text in one textbox like username , its updating the same user name on all browser session simultaneously.

Here is my code below `

```
    <div class="row" >
        <img src="./app/assets/images/20160113hoVirtualATM.jpg" 
             class="img-responsive center-block"
             style="max-height:300px;padding-bottom:50px"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row"  class="text-center" >
        <div>Login to Cardless Money</div>
        <br>
        <input class="center" type="text" name="userName" placeholder="User name" [(ngModel)]='userName'/>
        <br><br>
        <input class="center" type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]='password'/>
        <br><br>
       <button class='btn btn-primary' (click)='authenticate()'>
                        Login
          </button>
        <!-- <a [routerLink]="['Welcome']">Login</a> --> 
          <br><br>
           <a [routerLink]="['Signup']">Sign Up</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

`

and here is my welcome.component.ts-

```
constructor(public router: Router,
private _cardService: CardService) {}

authenticate(): void {
this.errorMessage="";
 this._cardService.authenticateUser(this.userName, this.password)
                 .subscribe(
                   isUserAuthenticated => this.isUserAuthenticated = isUserAuthenticated,
                   error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
console.log(this.isUserAuthenticated);
if(this.isUserAuthenticated.success === 'true'){
   this.router.parent.navigateByUrl('/landing?userName='+this.userName);
}else{
    this.errorMessage = 'Invalid User Credentials'; 
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because lite server on which application is running has synced browser with the application. Any change you perform in application will refresh all browser/tabs in which application is running.

Comment: Yes i am running my app on lite server.Is there any othe way to run my app.. currenlty i am using below command-                                                                         "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",

Comment: You can run your application on any http server. But you won't get auto refresh feature. command npm run tsc:w can be used to compile the application when running on different server.